# Virtual box - Can not install virtual box by Terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

I want to install `Virtual Box` but when run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` get the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  virtualbox : Depends: libgsoap8 but it is not installable
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

How to fix this problem and install Virtual Box?

Comment: You didn't install an external PPA, did you?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then running `sudo apt-get install libgsoap8 ` considering it's in the official repos (http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/libgsoap8) I really don't see why it's complaining...

Comment: @AndroidDev I try `sudo apt-get install libgsoap8` and get this error `E: Package 'libgsoap8' has no installation candidate`

Comment: 'Held broken packages' usually means you introduced a version conflict by installing software from a non-Ubuntu source. Delete the source and uninstall ALL software from that source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this on a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 (clean install) works for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

echo debconf virtualbox-ext-pack/license seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf virtualbox-ext-pack/license select true | sudo debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get -y install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

I use this snippet for installing it automatically on ephemeral test systems.

The issue of missing `libgsoap8` is probably about running `apt update` as they already mentioned by @AndroidDev.